# Can I configure IIS to route traffic to another server?

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, iis, virtual, blogs

I have a Windows server available at `website.com`, and I have another server with a WordPress on it.

How can I configure IIS to route `website.com/blog` to my WordPress?

I tried to use virtual directories, but I can only send my user to the same server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could consider using ARR reverse proxy to achieve your requirement.

I suggest you could install the ARR by using this [link](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) and this [link](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

Then I suggest you could try to use below url rewrite rule.

```
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="/blog/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://ec2 ubuntu address/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you,it worked but I had to add more code to my web.config.

My web.config:

```
<rewrite> 
            <rules> 
<clear />
                <rule name="Route the requests for Company1" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="false"> 
                    <match url="(.*)" /> 
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://" /> 
                    </conditions> 
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://blog.raczum.com/{R:0}" /> 
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" /> 
                    </serverVariables> 
                </rule> 

        <rule name="Route the subfolder blog" enabled="false" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="false"> 
                    <match url="https://raczum.com/blog/*" /> 
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://" /> 
                    </conditions> 
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://blog.raczum.com/{R:1}" /> 
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" /> 
                    </serverVariables> 
                </rule>             </rules> 
            <outboundRules> 
                <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false"> 
                    <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Frame, Head, IFrame, Img, Input, Link, Script" pattern="^http(s)?://blog.raczum.com/(.*)" /> 
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="/blog/{R:2}" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false" /> 
                </rule> 
                <rule name="RewriteRelativePaths" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false"> 
                    <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Frame, Head, IFrame, Img, Input, Link, Script" pattern="^http(s)?://blog.raczum.com/(.*)$" negate="false" /> 
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="/blog/{R:2}" /> 
                </rule> 
                <preConditions> 
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="*" /> 
                    </preCondition>
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml2">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition> 
                </preConditions> 
            </outboundRules> 
        </rewrite>
```